# Calling javascript function in a $( document ).ready function with string name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to call a function only if this function is defined. I try the following code in a node or browser console and it's work.

```
slurp = function() { console.log('slurp'); }
slurp_callable = ('slurp' in this && typeof(this['slurp']) == 'function');
console.log('slurp is callable (this)?', slurp_callable);
if (slurp_callable) { this['slurp'](); }
```

However, if i wait for document ready (using jquery):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  console.log( "ready!" );
  slurp = function() { console.log('slurp'); }
  console.log('slurp is callable (this)?',  ('slurp' in this && typeof(this['slurp']) == 'function')); //False
  console.log('slurp is callable (self)?',  ('slurp' in self && typeof(self['slurp']) == 'function')); //true
});
```

It return me false for this and true for self.

I understand that self is my previous this value, but when is my this changed and why?

How can I check and call a function into a $( document ).ready without using self?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically `self` will point to the `window.self`, if you do not override it.

```
slurp = function() { console.log('slurp'); }
```

Here you haven't mentioned the `var/let/..` defining method, hence the `slurp` will get assigned to the `window`.

So this code is,

```
('slurp' in self && typeof(self['slurp']) == 'function')
```

equals to

```
('slurp' in window.self && typeof(window.self['slurp']) == 'function').
```

Also `window.self == window`. Hence you are getting `true` as the result.

Answer (score 2):

The value of `this` depends on how the function it appears in is called.

In your first example you are calling it outside of any function, in the second example you are calling it in a function that is called as the ready event handler.

You can explicitly check if it is a global using `window` instead of `this` (in a browser).

Comment: Yes but in the second example, i'am not defining the function slurp also inside the function that is called when the ready event handler is call. That's what i don't understand. Why this function is not accessible in the current this.

Comment: @Naremy — In the second example, `slurp` is a global (so is the same as `window.slurp`) but `this` is not the same as `window` so `this.slurp` is `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the function:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log(this); // here this is the document
})
```

but if you write like following:

```
console.log(this); // this is window

$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log(this); // here this is the document
})
```

for more clarity you could try following:

```
console.log(this); // this is window
a = 10;
console.log(this.a); // 10

$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log(this); // here this is the document
    console.log(this.a); // undefined because a is not defined on the document

    // but you could access the one defined on the `window`
    console.log(window.a); // 10  

    b = 10;
    console.log(this.b); // still undefined because `b` is not set on the document but is local to this function.

    this.c = 10;
    console.log(this.c); // 10 
})
```